# ESLint: unignore subdirectory which is excluded by global pattern

Tags: javascript, eslint

Given a project structure as follows:

```
main
  ∟ dir1
      ∟ component-a.ts
      ∟ component-a.spec.ts
      ∟ component-b.ts
      ∟ component-b.spec.ts
  ∟ dir2
      ∟ component-c.ts
      ∟ component-c.spec.ts
  ∟ dir3
      ∟ subdir
          ∟ component-d.ts
          ∟ component-d.spec.ts
```

How can I **exclude** all `spec` files except the ones in `main/dir3/`?

By excluding the `*.spec.ts` pattern, I am unable to re-include the inner directory then unless I create an `.eslintrc.json` file inside it, but I would like not to have to duplicate the whole ruleset.

I've also tried changing the exclusion pattern to something like `**/!(dir3)/**/*.spec.ts`, but that doesn't seem to work.

My current config is as follows:

```json
{
  "root": true,
  "ignorePatterns": [...],
  ...
  "overrides": [
    {
      "files": ["*.ts"],
      "excludedFiles": [
        "*.spec.ts"
      ],
      "rules": {...}
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Hello, I guess you can use an .eslintignore file and use the method described here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5533050/gitignore-exclude-folder-but-include-specific-subfolder. Does that help?

Comment: It does, thanks! If you want to write an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a

> .eslintignore

file with a content like this:

> ```
> main/*
> !main/dir3
> ```

There is a more detailed description about this method here: [.gitignore exclude folder but include specific subfolder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5533050/gitignore-exclude-folder-but-include-specific-subfolder)